# Why is the value - despite of using GREATEST() - still out of range?

Tags: mysql, max

I tried the following to decrease a counter after a post was deleted by using `GREATEST()` so it does not result a negative value:

```
SELECT GREATEST(0, posts - 1)
FROM users
WHERE id = 123
```

but it returns:

```
[Err] 1690 - BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(`db1`.`users`.`posts` - 1)'
```

`posts` returns `0`:

```
SELECT posts
FROM users
WHERE id = 123
```

An the following returns `0` as expected:

```
SELECT GREATEST(0, 0 - 1)
```

So what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `posts` column is `BIGINT UNSIGNED` then unsigned values have to be `0` or more, so `-1` is out of range.

```
MariaDB [test]> desc tbl1;
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | bigint(20) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select id -1 from tbl1;
ERROR 1690 (22003): BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(`test`.`tbl1`.`id` - 1)'
```

Comment: I know `-1` is out of range. That is the reason why I used `GREATEST(0, -1)` resulting `0` but I see in your example that `id - 1` returns an error as well?! Isn't it possible to use the value of `id` for calculation only without letting MySQL checking the data type?

Comment: Ok, found a solution by using `SELECT GREATEST(0, CAST(posts AS SIGNED) - 1)`

Comment: @mgutt correct! You could also use `CASE WHEN points > 0 THEN points - 1 ELSE 0 END` instead of `GREATEST(...)`. It also voids the error in the (unlikely) event that `points` is in the very high range and cannot be converted to `SIGNED`.